# faild to make a new virtualenv having python2.7 and python3.6 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to use virtualenv to install some python modules for deep learning. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 where there was python2.7 intalled. Somehow I installed python 3 and made a virtualenv called dl4cv where I can work on deep learning projects. Now that I'm trying to make a new virtualenv `mkvirtualenv temp` after installing [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), I got an error as shown below :

```
hdafa@hdafa-HP-ProBook-450-G5:~$ mkvirtualenv temp
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2375, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 724, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 946, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1157, in install_python
    mkdir(lib_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 329, in mkdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/hdafa/.virtualenvs/temp'
```

any idea of how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You've been using `sudo` too much. Please stop.

First, fix permissions of your home:

```
sudo chown -R hdafa /home/hdafa
```

From now on please use only virtual environments and avoid `sudo` except for system administration tasks.

Comment: I hope this helped?

Comment: Yes! it works. I can now make new virtualenvs. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your OS is denying permission to make a directory. Try running the command with root permissions: `sudo mkvirtualenv temp`. The keyword `sudo` uses root permissions, and so it should be able to create the directory that it needs to.

Comment: Excessive use of `sudo` is exactly what led to this situation. Please do not advice `sudo` except for system administration tasks.

Comment: Then it may be the fact that it is using python2.7, not python3. If you temporarily set your python path to wherever python3 lives, it may work. You can do this by: `export PYTHONPATH=<yourpath>`, where your path is set to wherever python3 lives in your computer

Comment: Here I am, ['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/hdafa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'] please which of the list elements is the path?

Comment: It would be '/usr/lib/python3.6'